# Which compressed air and fluid are generally used by oleos?

Tags: landing-gear

Which compressed air and fluid are generally being used by oleo-struts?

Comment: Generally hydraulic oil and nitrogen (to reduce corrosion of the internal cylinders and seals).

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure it varies by aircraft type, but for the [C172S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cessna_172) nose gear oleo (for example) it's air and hydraulic fluid. The operating handbook says:

> Keep strut filled with [MIL-H-5606](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydraulic_fluid#Specifications) hydraulic fluid per filling
>   instructions placard, and with no load on the strut, inflate with air
>   to 45.0 PSI

Answer (score 1):

Generally Boeing struts use military hydraulic fluid (red oil) MIL-H-5606 and dry nitrogen as the charge. Many military aircraft have upgraded to synthetic hydraulic fluids that are fully compatible with MIL-H-5606, like MIL-PRF-83282 or MIL-PRF-87257. Sooner or later this will probably get adopted by airlines as well.